# Static function of database in Asp .net

Tags: asp.net, database, static

I have a class that gets tables from Sql Server. the class is static, but the variables are not. I want to know if it is OK in Asp net, because I had read not to use `static` at database in Asp net.

**My Class:** (There are more functions in the class, I put here one for example)

```
public static class DataBase
{
public static bool TableChange(string sqlCreate)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Global.ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCreate, connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.WriteLog(ex.Message + "\n" + sqlCreate, ex, HttpContext.Current.Request);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: there no variables in this class. compiler won't even allow you to put non-static members here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have read is most probably something to do with this approach:

```
public static EntityContext Database = new EntityContext();
// or
public static SqlConnection Database = new SqlConnection("...");
```

Here you store the database connection in a static variable and thus all parallel requests would want to use the same connection which is a very bad approach if it even works at all (it will probably work sort of fine until the page is under load).

You do not have this problem, because in your case only the methods are static, not the variables. Your code follows the recommended path - open connection (retrieve it from the pool), execute query, close the connection (return it to the pool).

Comment: Could you please explain how reading a static variable such as the connection string could cause an issue? - This is not a criticism of your answer - I just want to learn :) - Thanks.

Comment: @EmmadKareem - it is not an issue if the variable holds the connection string (which is a string). Is is an issue however, if the variable holds the actual connection object (which is an open TCP connection or something similar).